# import table from HDFS into spark

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

Is there a way to import a table from HDFS directly into spark and store it as an RDD or does it need to made into a textfile to do so?

ps - I get the table onto HDFS from my local system using sqoop  (if that matters) and When i do so it comes in the form of 4 files

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used sqoop before my self, you can use it to create hive tables which you can then query with [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) which will give you back SchemaRDDs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read.jdbc()` on your `sqlContext` to import a table from an external DB into a Spark DataFrame.